# "WARNING: Invalid auth configuration file" message while using helm3

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to use helm3 in my k8s cluster. I installed helm3 on one of the nodes and this happened.

[helm erro message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeNm1.png)

```
WARNING: Invalid auth configuration file
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config/configfile.decodeAuth
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/configfile/file.go:297
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config/configfile.(*ConfigFile).LoadFromReader
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/configfile/file.go:128
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config.load
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/config.go:130
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config.Load
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/config.go:111
oras.land/oras-go/pkg/auth/docker.NewClientWithDockerFallback
        oras.land/oras-go@v1.2.2/pkg/auth/docker/client.go:86
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry.NewClient
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry/client.go:83
main.newRootCmd
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/root.go:155
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:66
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
/root/.docker/config.json
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config.load
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/config.go:132
github.com/docker/cli/cli/config.Load
        github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.21+incompatible/cli/config/config.go:111
oras.land/oras-go/pkg/auth/docker.NewClientWithDockerFallback
        oras.land/oras-go@v1.2.2/pkg/auth/docker/client.go:86
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry.NewClient
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry/client.go:83
main.newRootCmd
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/root.go:155
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:66
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

I tried to install helm3 on another node, and worked fine. The difference between these two nodes is I have executed `docker login` command on the first node.  `~/.docker/config.json` file is automatically created. I removed the `config.json` file on first node, and helm worked properly.

I want to know how to make `docker login` and `helm` both work at same time. And I want to know why `docker login` and `helm` confilcted on my node, as well.

Comment: Helm exclusively uses the Kubernetes API and won't read the `$HOME/.docker` directory at all.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have the following file : /root/.docker/config.json and, if you do, you can rename this file and check if helm is running fine.